# app community and core file

Tags: magento2.1.5

I just did a fresh install of Magento 2.1.5 and there is not a folder for app/code/core or app/code/community

Where can I get all the files under the core and community folder?

I went through some tutorial online and they always reference files from these folders.

Is there a link where I can download the files and add them to these folders?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing Magento 1 with Magento 2. In Magento 2 there is not longer a split in the `app/code/` folder for code pools. Now everything is installed in vender namspaced folders in that one directory. So you have `app/code/Yourawesomecompany/Yourawesomemodule/` for every third party module or your custom code.

For the "core" code, in Magento 2 that now all lives under the `vendor/` directory in the root of your site's install. For Magento core code, that can be found in `vendor/magento/`.

One thing to take note of is that if you install a module with composer or with the install wizard in the admin of your site, their code can install in `vender`.

And if you are looking at tutorials for Magento 2 that were written for Magento 1, they will not work. They are completely different frameworks with completely different ways of interacting and writing custom code. As with all things Magento, Alan Storm has you covered for a great introduction to the new system:

http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_mvvm_mvc/